# Socket - Simple Server/Client - socket.error: [Errno 10060]

Tags: python, sockets

I have a very simple Socket Server code running on port 9999.  When I fire up my server and client, with netstat I can see that the server is running and the client is on the ephemeral port of 7180.

```
TCP    192.168.1.117:9999     0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       7180
```

However, the output of client shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 6, in <module>
    clisock.connect((host, 9999))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 222, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

My server code:

```
import socket
import sys
import time

srvsock = socket.socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Server Socket is Created'

host = socket.gethostname()
try:
    srvsock.bind( (host, 9999) )
except socket.error ,  msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

srvsock.listen(5)
print 'Socket is now listening'

while True:
    clisock, (remhost, remport) = srvsock.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + remhost + ':' + str(remport)
    currentTime = time.ctime(time.time()) + "\r\n"
    print currentTime
    clisock.send(currentTime)

clisock.close()
srvsock.close()
```

And my Socket client program is as follow:

```
import socket
clisock = socket.socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = socket.gethostname()
print host
clisock.connect((host, 9999))


tm = clisock.recv(1024)

clisock.close()

print tm
```

What is the issue? Could it be a Firewall or something which cause the connection to drop?

Comment: Why are you using socket.gethostname() and not 'localhost' or 127.0.0.1? It is more reliable than socket.gethostname().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that `socket.gethostname()` will return a FQDN. Try to bind the server to `''` (empty string is a symbolic name meaning all available interfaces), then connect your client to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Python documentation includes a very useful example for creating a simple TCP server-client application using  low-level socket API [1].

[1] https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example